# Some of unit tests failed on Azure but passed locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

What's happened. We have a service in out project that generates PDF documents. So, we have tests that check if two documents are equal. First document, called "Expected" we already have locally as a template document in Baseline folder. Second document, called "Actual" or "Result" generated automatically by our service. Here the code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void PdfExportProviderTest()
    {
        var document = GetDocument("Pdf document");

        IExportProvider pdfExportProvider = new PDFExportProvider();
        var stream = pdfExportProvider.Export(document, DisplayUnits.Imperial);

        var resultPdf = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        var expectedPdf = GetPdfByName("ExpectedDocument.pdf");

        Assert.IsTrue(Clear(expectedPdf).Equals(Clear(resultPdf), StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
    }
```

(Clear method remove all randomly or dynamic generated information from PDF (such as Creation info, ID etc)

As you can see, we convert our PDF files two UTF-8 strings and compare them. All tests successfully pass locally. But when we push it on Azure, Azure Pipeline generates the report, where some of (NOT ALL!) PDF tests are failed.
What I've already tried:

1. Converted Result and Actual string to one Encoding (UTF-8) - no result
2. Removed hidden none-printed symbols using this expression: Regex.Replace(text.Trim(), @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", "*");
3. I generated the differences to check, what's wrong on Azure and when I've got these files generated I see, that lines, that might be different - where the equals.
4. I used the same Culture by setting second option "StringComparison.CurrentCulter" in the Equals method.
5. All .cs files are UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information presented the problem may lie with "GetDocument". I would check to make sure that GetDocument is actually returning a document in Azure.  If the document is part of the solution then make sure that it gets copied over with the build artifacts and that your build agent has access to it.  If the document is being fetched from an external source then use a mocking framework (Moq is a good one) and mock the document for your test to use.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but he method GetDocument returns already mocked document, not real!

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried comparing the byte array of the 2 PDFs?  I don't know what your Clear method is doing, but since you have the stream you can just fetch the bytes and do a CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedBytes, actualBytes)

Comment: Thanks, I've already used this way! The problem was that PDF files were generated on the Azure and when I review them in the text mode, I found that after each line a new line return symbol with code 13 (Carriage Return) was added. After that I cleaned these symbols and now everything is great!